# Jquery not serializing my radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I can not get the result of the radio button and checkbox with jquery serialize()

what is the problem?

I put the code to see if you can help me, since all other elements process them correctly.

```js
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  var type = "POST";
  var url = $(this, "form").prop("action");

  if (event.target.files) {
    var file = event.target.files;
    var elementos = $(this, "form")[0].elements;

    var data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
      element = elementos[i];
      data.append(element.name, element.value);
    }

    var file_data = $(file).prop("files")[0];
    data.append("files", file_data);

    var cache = false;
    var contentType = false;
    var processData = false;
  } else {
    var data = $(this, "form").serialize();
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      type: type,
      cache: cache,
      contentType: contentType,
      processData: processData

    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $(".section").html(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="1"> Hombre
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="2"> Mujer
```

Comment: Where is the '<form>` in your html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the selector you're using. `$(this, "form")` is looking for the current `form` within another `form` element. Just use `$(this)` in all places instead. Also note that you can make the code much simpler by providing the `form` element reference to the `FormData()` constructor. This will have the exact same result as your current code. Try this:

```js
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  var type = "POST";
  var url = $(this).prop("action");
  var cache = false;
  var contentType = true;
  var processData = true;

  if (this.files.length) {
    var data = new FormData(this);
    contentType = false;
    processData = false;
  } else {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      type: type,
      cache: cache,
      contentType: contentType,
      processData: processData
    }).done(function(data) {
      $(".section").html(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="1"> Hombre
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="2"> Mujer
```

Comment: If thanks, :-) but the input type = "radio" still does not work, it always returns as a result 2

Comment: There is no updated cache, it does not work, it gives me error is Chrome console --> `Uncaught TypeError: (o.contentType || "").indexOf is not a function` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`